# Python script to interact with fdisk prompts automatically

Tags: python, linux, bash

This Python program enters fdisk.  I see the output.  fdisk is an interactive program.  How do I get the Python program to pass an "m" to the first field and press enter?

```
import subprocess
a = "dev/sda"
x = subprocess.call(["fdisk", a])
print x
```

I'd rather not import a new module/library, but I could.  I've tried different syntax with subprocess.call() and extra parameters in the above.  Nothing seems to work.  I get different errors. I've reviewed Python documentation.  I want to feed input and press Enter in the subsequent, interactive menu options of fdisk.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) library (I know you didn't want an extra module, but you want to use the best tool for the job). It's pure Python, with no compiled submodules, so installation is a snap. Basically, it does the same thing in Python as the classic Unix utility [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) - spawns child applications, controls them, and responds to expected patterns in their output. It's great for automation, and especially application testing, where you can quickly feed the newest build of a command-line program a series of inputs and guide the interaction based on what output appears.

In case you just don't want another module at all, you can always fall back on the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module's [`Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) constructor. It spawns and creates a connection to a child process, allowing you to communicate with it as needed, and in fact `pexpect` relies a great deal on it. I personally think using `pexpect` is more intuitive than `subprocess.Popen()`, but that's just me. YMMV.

Comment: Popen and writing to stdin is all that is needed

Comment: @PadraicCunningham true, but I find `pexpect` much easier to use. I'll make a mention of it in the answer.

Comment: Yep pexpect is definitely a better general tool but you might as well throw in the popen solution though as it is pretty straight forward.